# javascript pop up boxes

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

i'm trying to make a small pop up box but i am unable to..i've not gone too far with it, this is the code i have so far, it only displays a small box with nothing written in it..i would like to use strictly javascript, no jquery, the popup box should be interactive and should close when clicked outside the box..

```
<style>#popup{display: none; height: 500px; width: 500px; position: absolute; top: 5pc; right:20pc;</style>

<div id="popup"></div>

<script>
function popupbox(elem)
{

    var popup = document.getElementById('elem');
    if( popup.style.display == 'none' )
    {
        popup.style.display = 'block';
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: How about using an external library, like [jsModal](http://jsmodal.com/)?

Comment: i don't wanna use any libraries..i wanna code from scratch..so i can learn how to make libraries as well..thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Then you will be best served by reviewing how it has already been done. You can view the [jsModal source](https://code.google.com/p/jsmodal/source/browse/js/jsmodal-1.0c.js) and see that it can get quite complex very quickly. Good luck!

Comment: thank you..i shall have a look at the jsModal source

Comment: i love the source code of js modal, it's easy to understand :)

Comment: JsModal is a great resource because of how well written it is. It has been amazingly useful for me. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together an overly simplistic [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/4fLSW/1/) of how a popup is made. Here is the magic:

```
//Display Popup method - you can modify this to add parameters 
function displayPopup(event) {
        //dynamically create a div, button, and inner text
        var p = document.createElement('div'),
            b = document.createElement('button'),
            t = document.createTextNode("Text and stuff");

    //add popup class to newly created div
    p.className += 'popup';
    //Add text to close button element
    b.innerHTML = "close";
    //Append text to popup div
    p.appendChild(t);
    //Bind click event to button element
    b.onclick = closePopup;
    //Append button to popup div, and append popup to document body
    p.appendChild(b);
    document.body.appendChild(p);

    p.style.display="block";

    //This function hides the popup
    function closePopup(event){
        p.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

It should by no means be considered complete or production material, but I hope it helps you get started on the right path to extending it to achieve the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: this helped a lot, you're using the event handler pretty well, all of these answers combined, i can make pop up boxes.

Answer (score 2):

It can be very easily done using pure CSS and JS...

Please find here the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitjc/P6QwM/2/)** - Please let me know if this helps.

Your popup html code can be like-

```
<div id="click" onClick="showPopUp()">Click here to see the pop up</div>
<div id="popup">
    <div id="header">Welcome to Pop-Up
        <img src="http://icongal.com/gallery/image/158734/actions_window_close.png" width="20px" onclick="closeThis()" />
    </div>
    <div>THIS IS THE TEXT OF POP-UP</div>
</div>
```

---

Basic CSS -

```
#popup {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    left:50%;
    top:10px;
}
```

---

JS Code -

1) To Show the popup on click of the text

```
    function showPopUp() {
        document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    }
```

2) To check/hide a pop up when clicked anywhere else on the page -

```
    document.onclick=check;
    function check(e) {
            var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
            var obj = document.getElementById('click');
            if(target!=obj){document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none'}
    }
```

Comment: I +1'd because I like it, but it's not interactive?

Comment: this is some good code..i like it but i agree with dcromley, it isn't interactive and it's using inline event target, it works fine though, i get an idea of how to close the popup box.

Comment: Yes, I did not code it completely, just wanted to know if this is what Hawk was trying to achieve... Can be made interactive with a li'l effort though.

Comment: true, i thank you for that information, it works perfectly. it is a good start

Comment: Glad u liked it... All the best with your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to do a pop box, use window.open:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open3 


<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open an a new window called "MsgWindow" with some text.</p>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open "MsgWindow"</button>

<script>
function openWin()
{
var myWindow = window.open("","MsgWindow","width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:
za.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dopopup() {
  var popup1 = window.open("zb.htm", "", "width=400, height=300");
  popup1.focus();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="dopopup()">Make Popup</button>
</body>
</html>
```

zb.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function fnonblur() {
  window.close();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onblur="fnonblur();">
Hello, world.
<button onclick="alert('Hello, again.');")>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```